# Return a trait that uses a derived trait

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'd like to create a typeclass that knows how to return an HList as well as a derived HList.  Ideally it would have a structure along the lines of:

```
trait Axis[A, L1 <: HList] {
  type L2 <: Mapped[L1,Ordering]#Out
  def vectorize(a:A): L1
  def orderings: L2
}
```

and would be implemented like

```
implicit object Tup2DI extends Axis[(Double, Int), Double :: Int :: HNil] {
  val m = implicitly[Mapped[Double :: Int :: HNil, Ordering]]
  type L2 = m.Out
  def vectorize(a: (Doubble, Int)) = a._1 :: a._2 :: HNil
  def orderings = implicitly[Ordering[Double]] :: implicitly[Ordering[Int]] :: HNil
}
```

The issue is that scala isn't reifying the type and so during compilation, despite having enough information to determine the type, resulting in this error:

```
 found   : shapeless.::[Ordering[Double],shapeless.::[Ordering[Int],shapeless.HNil]]
 required: Tup2DI.L2
    (which expands to)  Tup2DI.m.Out
             def orderings:L2 = implicitly[Ordering[Double]] :: implicitly[Ordering[Int]] :: HNil
```

How can I express the information I care about in a way that will compile correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after talking it through with the ever knowledgeable folks on #scala, the following work around was pointed out to me:

```
trait Axis[A, L1 <: HList] {
  val L2: Mapped[L1,Ordering]
  def vectorize(a:A): L1
  def orderings: L2.Out
}
object Axis {
  def reifiedT[L1 <: HList](implicit M: Mapped[L1,Ordering]): Mapped[L1,Ordering] {
    type Out = M.Out
  } = M
}

implicit object Tup2DI extends Axis[(Double, Int), Double :: Int :: HNil] {
  val L2 = Axis.reifiedT[L]
  def vectorize(a: (Double, Int)) = a._1 :: a._2 :: HNil
  def orderings:L2.Out = implicitly[Ordering[Double]] :: implicitly[Ordering[Int]] :: HNil
}
```

Apparently you have to tell scala to set the reified Out type explicitly, a technique that's used in the Scalaz library.